# Issues with converting a date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my data that is full of 'dates' that are formatted like `030816` and have a datatype of Varchar. I've been trying all morning to convert this number to a date format of `03/08/2016`. Nothing I seem to do gives me the desired results. Here's what I've tried:

- I changed the column datatype from Varchar to Date. This resulted in a more acceptable date format, but also resulted in changing the date completely. Upon this conversion the dates that are supposed to read `03/08/2016` ended up reading `2003-08-16`.
- I tried keeping the datatype as a Varchar, and using `Convert(Varchar(10),Bill_Date,103)` when building out my select query, but this resulted in no change and continued to display the results as `030816`
- I also tried using `Cast(Bill_Date AS Date)`, but this also provides me with a result of `2003-08-16`, which again is not the correct date.
- Lastly, I tried `Format(Bill_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY')`, but this gave me an error message claiming that the Argument data type Varchar is invalid for the argument.

Is there a way to get SQL to either convert this string of numbers to the date format I need or at the very least is there a way to display the string of numbers in a select query that will give me the format I need?

Comment: the `DATE` and `DATETIME` data types don't have a format, they just display the results some way depending on the regional settings. Do you actually want a `varchar`in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format, or an actual `DATE`?. How would you know if `030816` is `03/08/2016` instead of `03/08/1916` or `03/08/2116`?

Comment: Did you try using SUBSTRING to make up an ISO8601 formatted date string? See also CONVERT(datetime, @val, 126)

Comment: @lamak I'm less concerned I guess about the actual datatype and more concerned about how it is displayed. I'll settle for whatever gets me the `MM/DD/YYYY` format. As for knowing the difference between `2016` and `1916`, the data that I'm using is  downloaded on a monthly basis and  will never have data pre-dating a year ago much less 100 years ago, and if this system is still around in 2116, then I've either done something really right or the world has done something really wrong lol.

Comment: Then you could just do `SELECT LEFT(YourColumn,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(YourColumn,3,2) + '/20' + RIGHT(YourColumn,2)`

Comment: @lamak that got me the display I needed. Make it an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks

Comment: The absolute best way to solve is to stop storing dates in a varchar column. Storing "dates" as varchar is unbelievably problematic. There are just way too many things that can wrong. Then you run into challenges like you are facing now. If this was stored as dates you would have no issue at all. Of course, any formatting really belongs in the front end and NOT in sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange and that's the reason I don't want to post an answer ;-)

Comment: @SeanLange While I do agree with you, how am I supposed to store this as a date, when it automatically changes the "date" to a date that is inaccurate? Formatting on the front end was my first choice, but because the way the data was being displayed, Excel (our front end) was reading it as a serial date. Now I could create an Excel macro that performs the same steps that Lamak provided, but I would prefer to not deal with creating another step on front end if possible.

Comment: What I mean is the datatype in your table should be a date instead of varchar. You will still have to do some ugly conversion like the answers posted here but that would hopefully be a one time thing instead of ongoing.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates (D VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Dates
        (D)
VALUES  ('030816'),
        ('123049'),
        ('013055'),
        ('123099')

select convert (datetime,  Stuff(Stuff(d,5,0,'.20'),3,0,'.'))

FROM #Dates

DROP TABLE #Dates
```

You will need to do math on your specific data set to replace the `'.20'` with `'19'` if some of your dates are prior to 2000-01-01.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the value to a *date*, not from a date:

```
select Convert(date, Bill_Date, 3)
```

The appropriate format would appear to be "3".

If you need a string afterwards, you can convert it back to MM/DD/YYYY format using 101.

Comment: Reason for a downvote?  If this is wrong, a comment would be helpful.

Comment: not my downvote, but your query gives a different result than the one wanted by op, that might be it

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TABLE SampleData(
DescSample VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES ('030816')

SELECT LEFT(DescSample, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(DescSample,3,2) + '/' + '20' + RIGHT(DescSample, 2)

FROM SampleData

-- Just the format you want
-- You should use proper year format. -_-

Comment: -1. Lazy near copy/paste of an answer posted 12 hours earlier. Oh, only of the code part - because you did not even copy the explanation.

Comment: at the very least is there a way to display the string of numbers in a select query that will give me the format I need? -- He says this. I give him the idea of using left right in sql .